# Connecting CDK and SageMaker pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sagemaker

Suppose that you have some services hosted on AWS, where you've used CDK as the Infrastructure as Code solution. Independently, you've created a machine learning resources using SageMaker pipelines. What is the recommended method to connect these resources?

I could see many reasons why one might want to define a new service in CDK that interfaces smoothly with resources defined by SageMaker pipelines.

Perhaps I'm over complicated it and it's as simple as creating two packages, the CDK and SM Pipeline, both using the same AWS account and simply pass references between resources using ARN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you are referring to how does a CDK project and a SageMaker Pipelines project work alongside, the way I see it is that the SageMaker Pipelines project is code you version, change and deliver the changes, and this also needs to resources, such as S3 bucket, IAM roles, the CI/CD pipelines for delivery changes you made to the SageMaker Pipelines code.

I have been using the following approach, where I separate the model build and model deploy code in separate repos, mostly, because the changes made to each are not at the same time. For each repo, I have a CI/CD pipeline to deliver changes. The following diagram shows how the architecture looks like:

[image]

For running the SageMaker Pipelines code, as it is code that needs to be executed `python src/run_pipeline.py`, I use codebuild for this and my CI/CD pipelines have some environment variables defined for IAM roles to use, S3 bucket, etc. All of the resources you see outside the SageMaker Pipelines Workflow boxes is built using CDK.

I can't share the code now for the CDK, but I might put a similar code in my personal repo in the upcoming weeks.